# Pasting the SUM of Negative values through SUMPRODUCT and SUMIFS

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I have been using the below formula which SUM the Sheet2 values and Present Them in Sheet3.

Now i have been trying to add one more condition that is the formula should SUM the just Negative Values from the Range `Sheet2!D2:D30` When `Sheet2 Col"L"` cell is not empty and Paste them in Sheet3.

I have attached a Sheet link which may help to solve the problem.

Here is original formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(Sheet2!D2:D30,Sheet2!I2:I30,Sheet1!I2:I30)*(Sheet1!D2:D30=A3))
```

After i have added one more condition but its not working

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(Sheet2!D2:D30,Sheet2!I2:I30,Sheet1!I2:I30)*(Sheet1!D2:D30=A3)*(Sheet2!L2:L30<>""))
```

any help will be much appreciated.

Result will be like this:

[image]

Sheet Link

[Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Viv50qbo1fFW_sGcMpaZQ7qLeu8GkMXDILSr7WBZmXU/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: sheet2 items will all need to be part of the SUMIFS.

Comment: what is in L when it is not blank?

Comment: Yes Sheet2 all items will be part of SUMIFS, L is actually a Refund comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To only sum the negative values, you can just add that as a condition in your SUMIFS:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(Sheet2!D2:D30,Sheet2!D2:D30,"<0",Sheet2!I2:I30,Sheet1!I2:I30)*(Sheet1!D2:D30=A3))
```